# Reasons for SyncError and resolution in V3

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, ipp-qbd-sync

What causes a SyncError in V3 and how do you resolve it? If it is validation-related, why is the API unable to handle it? Lastly, is there ever an indication to the QBD user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve this prob using V2 API.

PFB links related to Sync process

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0300_sync_manager

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0400_data_synchronization

To know which object are in error state, please refer

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0100_calling_data_services/0015_retrieving_objects

You may also be interested to know why those objects are in error state. For that, please refer Status API.
Ex -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<CustomerQuery ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
</CustomerQuery>
```

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/syncstatus

```
<SyncStatusRequest ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <NgIdSet>
        <NgId>1527022</NgId>
        <NgObjectType>Invoice</NgObjectType>
    </NgIdSet>
    <StartCreatedTMS>1986-02-05T14:51:18.038+05:30</StartCreatedTMS>
    <EndCreatedTMS>2015-11-05T14:51:18.038+05:30</EndCreatedTMS>
</SyncStatusRequest>
```

You can try all these calls using API Explorer.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

In V3, above APIs are not supported yet.
V3 supported entity and operations - 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations

Thanks

Comment: There is an indication to the user in the Blue Dot Menu widget, there is a color coded sync icon that tells the user if there is an error. (Red, Yellow or Green)